# Why is dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects not returning the full set of redirect links? (Sparql)

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am using the following query :

```
select ?value where { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Paris>  dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects* ?value }
```

in order to retrieve the `wikiPageRedirects` property of Paris.

---

Based on [dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/page/Paris) Paris has more than *20* redirect links. Why am I only retrieving the first one?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your direction was wrong.

```sql
select distinct *
where { 
  ?x dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Paris>
}
```

Comment: so you defined it as a label? I didn't really understand the query I am fairly new to sparql. It worked perfectly tho

Comment: So when you are looking for the properties in dbpedia, it is good to look at how they are defined. If you follow the link to dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects, you can see that one way it is defined is as a label. You should read the SPARQL manual, it has great examples.

Comment: Actually, if you don't want the labels, it works without the first line as well. Your direction was wrong. I misunderstood your question, and though you needed the value of the links.

Comment: For the label ok I get it no problem. But do you mean that I had the query upside down?

Answer (score 2):

[Artemis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28767614/1281433) is right;  the "direction" in the query is wrong.  It's worth explaining that a bit more, though. On the DBpedia "page", you'll see lots of data like:

> ```
> dbpedia-owl:area      105400000.000000 (xsd:double)  
> dbpedia-owl:country   dbpedia:France  
> dbpedia-owl:inseeCode 75056 (xsd:integer)  
> dbpedia-owl:mayor     dbpedia:Anne_Hidalgo
> ```

These mean that DBpedia contains triples where these are the predicates and objects.  That is, DBpedia contains a triple:

```
dbpedia:Paris dbpedia-owl:country dbpedia:France
```

On other hand, you'll also see things like "is … of":

> ```
> is dbpedia-owl:beatifiedPlace of dbpedia:Daniel_Brottier
> is dbpedia-owl:billed         of dbpedia:René_Duprée
> ```

These mean that dbpedia:Paris the *object* of triples with these subjects and predicates.  E.g., DBpedia contains the triple

```
dbpedia:René_Duprée dbpedia-owl:billed dbpedia:Paris
```

The redirects properties that you're seeing are like this:

```
is dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects of dbpedia:City_of_Love_(city)
                                    dbpedia:Département_de_Paris
                                    dbpedia:Departement_de_Paris
                                    dbpedia:FRPAR
```

That means that there are a bunch of triples of the form:

```
?something dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects dbpedia:Paris
```

and that means that your query needs to be

```sql
select ?resource where {
  ?resource dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects dbpedia:Paris
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fresource%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fresource%20dbpedia-owl%3AwikiPageRedirects%20dbpedia%3AParis%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Really interesting Joshua. I am actually practicing on your comments with examples from bpedia.org/sparql. trying to form these relations between the triples.

Comment: select * where {?x dbpedia-owl:country dbpedia:United_States} For example this will return everything where the country is the united states?

Comment: one last question how about  "wikiPageRedirects, wikiPageInLinkCountCleaned" these are also properties that i am also extracting but in a very complex way. First i select all the properties for a given concept then I try to search for them in the resulting query.

Comment: Yes, that query will select things that have the value dbpedia:United_States as the value of dbpedia-owl:country.

Comment: @HaniGoc I'm not sure what you're asking in your third comment, but it sounds like you might need a subquery.  You should probably ask a new question about that.