# Query DBPedia on "is [property] of"

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to obtain a list of "is [property] of" items.

For example, [Barack Obama on DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/page/Barack_Obama) has both "successor" as property and "is successor of" properties (with different successors!).

The first I can get with the following SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX ont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX obama: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama>
SELECT ?successor
WHERE{  
    obama: ont:successor ?successor
}
```

How, can I get the list of items that satisfy "is successor of" criteria?

Comment: the "is property of "jsut means the triple goes inteh other direction. if you see "X is [p] of Y", you'd query with "?y p ?x".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely, most of the `is [property] of` are defined as a `has [property]`. For example, the `is successor of` is defined as `predecessor`. Thus in your case you need to change your query to:

```
PREFIX obama: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama>
SELECT *
WHERE{  
    obama: dbpprop:predecessor ?successor
}
```

Just explore the main properties of DBpedia and such things pop out. Or as Jashua mentioned change the direction of the query:

```
PREFIX obama: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama>
SELECT *
WHERE{  
      ?successor dbpprop:successor obama:
}
```

Comment: This problem is the same issue as mentioned in [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28765205/1281433) (one where you posted the accepted answer, actually).  Since the issue is the same (when we see "X [is P of] Y", the pattern needs to be "?y p ?x"), I think it probably would have made more sense to flag as a duplicate.

Comment: I saw the flag after I posted the answer. True enough!