# How to get 'is dct:subject of' property from dbpedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, ontology, dbpedia

I need to get related topics for a wikipedia page say upto 5 levels. For a page `Mathematics`, I get this using:

`select ?value where { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Mathematics> skos:broader{0,4} ?value }`

This does not work for `Science`(http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Science) since the broader at each level points back to `Science_and_technology`,`Main_topic_classifications` etc. This is happenning since Science is high up in the ontology unlike Category:Mathematics. So I try to use the property `is skos:broader of`. Is this a valid property? How do I handle the spaces here? Using `skos:broader` alone does not give intended result.

Comment: "is PROPERTY of" -> inverse relation, i.e. the entity `e` is the object in an RDF triple, e.g. `(a, PROPERTY, e)`. That means you have to invert the triple pattern. Or you simply use the inverse relation which is unsurprisingly `skos:narrower` and hope that the inverse triples exist. I'd go for the first solution: `select ?value where { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Mathematics> ^skos:broader{0,4} ?value }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Inverse relation should do it. So now this would be traversing the tree upward. Would using  `dct:subject` instead get the succeeding nodes?

Comment: "succeeding nodes" - not sure what you mean by that but it get's all entities that belong to the category: `select ?value where { 
  ?value dct:subject/^skos:broader{0,4}  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Mathematics>  }`

Comment: I wrote about this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28768818/1281433).

Comment: Thanks @AKSW. It works with ^skos:broader{0,4}.

Comment: @Joshua unlike the question you answered, my intention is to get the hierarchy in the same direction. Since the results are all at high level, I wanted to know how to query the opposite direction. So now my logic changes to 'go one level up(is skos:broader of) and then find all the categories with skos:broader of relation with it'. I am trying to build a dictionary of topics in subject Science.