# How to get the WikiPageRedirects attribute for a dbpedia resource

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

I want to write a sparql query to return the WikiPageRedirects attribute for a given dbpedia resource.

For example: MongoDB has 3 as depicted here https://dbpedia.org/page/MongoDB

I write this query to get them:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?alias
WHERE {
    VALUES (?resource) { (dbo:MongoDB) }
    ?resource dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?alias .
}
```

but it does not display anything [sparql](https://dbpedia.org/sparql)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues involved:

- The URI of the the resource *MongoDB* is not `dbo:MongoDB` (→ `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/MongoDB`), but `dbr:MongoDB` (→ `http://dbpedia.org/resource/MongoDB`).
- The property `dbo:wikiPageRedirects` has to be used [in the other direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28768818/19579546). On the linked *MongoDB* page, this is indicated by the "is … of" ("is `dbo:wikiPageRedirects` of").

So your query could be:

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?alias
WHERE {
    VALUES (?resource) { (dbr:MongoDB) }
    ?resource ^dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?alias .
}
```

or:

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?alias
WHERE {
    VALUES (?resource) { (dbr:MongoDB) }
    ?alias dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?resource .
}
```